# Jquery-Validation check for two text boxes

Tags: jquery

```
function validate()
    {
     var textbox= $("#inputtextbox").val();
     var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
     if(!match.test(textbox)) {
     $("#dataError").text('Min 1 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
    return false;
    }

var textbox= $("#inputtextbox").val();
     var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
     if(!match.test(textbox)) {
     $("#dataErr").text('Min 1 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
    return false;
    }
}
```

I've a form and two text boxes.I'm validating two text boxes.Say,when i do not fill both text boxes and click submit button,it is only print the error message for first textbox.
When i fill every thing properly in first text box and i do not fill any thing in second text,now if i submit,it is showing error message for second text box,why is it not showing the message,when both not filled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<input id="box_1" class="textbox" value="" />
<span></span>

<input id="box_2" class="textbox" value="" />
<span></span>

$('#form').submit(function(){

var valid = validate();

if(valid)
{
   //do submit
}

});


function validate()
    {

     var result = true;

     $('.textbox').each(function(){

     var textbox= $(this).val();

     var text_id = $(this).attr('id');

     if(text_id = 'box_1')
     {
         var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;   
     }
     else if(text_id = 'box_2')
     {
         var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;   
     }

     if(!match.test(textbox)) {
        $(this).next('span').text('Min 1 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
        result = false;
        }
    });

return result;

    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
function validate()
    {

     var valid = true ;

     var textbox= $("#inputtextbox_1").val();
     var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
     if(!match.test(textbox)) {
     $("#dataError_1").text('Min 1 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
    valid  = false;
    }

var textbox= $("#inputtextbox_2").val();
     var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
     if(!match.test(textbox)) {
     $("#dataErr_2").text('Min 1 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
    valid = false;
    }

   return valid;
}
```

Comment: :Second text box will have a different regex,i've not updated in my question.

Comment: :What is wrong in my code?Instead of writing some thing from scratch,i can correct my code.

Comment: then use different ID's for input boxes and error div's , note that you can not use 2 id's width same name , ill will updade my answer

Comment: :That is my full code,can a function have two return statement.

Comment: no you can not have , return false; exit's from you code , sorry i forgot it ,i will update my code ,

Answer (score 2):

Both of your validations are referring to the same jquery object $("#dataError"), therefore, it can only show up one error message since there is only data error box.

If you want both to show up, you need to create a second data error box.